# Ruby if else statement

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I am being asked to:

> Define a method called `first_longer_than_second` with a parameter called `first` and another called `second`. The method will `return true` if the first word passed in is greater than or equal to the length of the second word. It `returns false` otherwise.

This is the code I have come up with:

```
def first_longer_than_second(first, second)
  if first >= second
      return true;
  else
      return false;
  end
end
```

The calls I am making:

```
first_longer_than_second('pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis', 'k') #=> false
first_longer_than_second('apple', 'prune') #=> true
```

---

For some reason on repl.it I only get the output `false`

And i get this error message on the platform I am actually meant to be completing this task on:

```
expected #<TrueClass:20> => true
     got #<FalseClass:0> => false

Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
`expect(actual).to eq(expected)` if you don't care about
object identity in this example.

exercise_spec.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

---

Tried a number of things, but annoyingly stuck with something that seems should be simple...

Comment: *"if the first word passed in is greater than or equal to the length of the second word"* -- I cannot see in your code where you use the length of the second word. Also, from the test cases it seems you should compare the length of the first argument (and not its value).

Comment: aaaaaahh MONDAY MORNING BRAIN FREEZE!

Thank you!

Comment: @axiac put in an answer and i'll approve

Comment: And you don't need an `if` statement, just `first.length >= second.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Define a method called `first_longer_than_second` with a parameter called `first` and another called `second`. The method will return `true` if the `first` word passed in is greater than or equal to the length of the `second` word. It returns `false` otherwise.

Your code:

```
def first_longer_than_second(first, second)
  if first >= second
      return true;
  else
      return false;
  end
end
```

First of all, your code doesn't follow the requirements. They ask to compare the lengths of the two arguments. The `if` condition should be:

```
if first.length >= second.length
```

See the documentation of [`String#length`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-length).

---

Regarding the syntax of Ruby, the semicolons (`;`) after the statements are not needed. Like in Javascript, a Ruby statement can be terminated using a semicolon but also a newline. The semicolon is useful to separate two statements on the same line.

Next, the same as in Javascript (and many other languages), you can directly return the result of the comparison (and not put it into an `if` statement that returns `true`/`false`):

```
def first_longer_than_second(first, second)
  return first.length >= second.length
end
```

One last improvement to make it look like Ruby (and not Javascript or PHP): a Ruby function returns the value of the last expression it computes; this makes the presence of the `return` keyword superfluous here.

Your code should be:

```
def first_longer_than_second(first, second)
  first.length >= second.length
end
```

Comment: thank you for all the added info! really helpful for me going forward!!